# Sublime Text no build output

Tags: c++, build, output, sublimetext, pawn

Using build option does not give any output except of

```
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

I didn't configure any c++.sublime-build file, I just installed C++ compiler and added it to the system path. It should work out of the box, but it is not. I also use Pawn language very often, but I had to configure my pawn.sublime-build file in order to work. There is a similar problem, after building if there are some errors it says:

```
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

But if the code has no errors, it says:

```
Welcome to the AMX Mod X 1.8.1-300 Compiler.
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 ITB CompuPhase, AMX Mod X Team

Header size:            836 bytes
Code size:             5048 bytes
Data size:             2148 bytes
Stack/heap size:      16384 bytes; estimated max. usage=883 cells (3532 bytes)
Total requirements:   24416 bytes
Done.
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

It would by nice if sublime could just show the output from compiler.

Here's my Pawn.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["amxxpc.exe", "$file"],
    // "cmd": ["compile.exe"],
    // "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "file_regex": "(.*)\\((\\d+)\\)\\s*:\\s*()(.*)",
    "selector": ["source.pwn", "source.pawn", "source.sma", "source.inc"],
    "path": "Extensions\\pawn\\"
}
```

I tried diffrent versions of the "file_regex" and also without it, just like in tutorials, but it just doesn't show output if code has an error.

On the other hand, Python shows up an output, like this:

```
    print"test")
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Michał\OneDrive\Documents\test.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Michał\OneDrive\Documents]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 9\;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\MinGW\bin]
```

And here's output with corrected code:

```
test
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

How can I get output from C++ and Pawn files?
What I am doing wrong?
I use MinGW for C++ and amxxpc.exe (AMX MOD X COMPILER) for pawn.
Thank you in advance for any solution and sorry for my english. I'm from Poland.

Answer (score 1):

Open up Sublime Text 2 and go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...

Enter the following:

```
 {
    "cmd": ["pawncc.exe", "-i includes", "$file", "-;+"],
    "path": "C:/path/to/pawno/folder"
}
```

Of course you need to replace the path

Save this file and close Sublime Text 2

Now navigate to AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User

Open up the .sublime-keymap file based on your operating system

Enter the following (this example is for the Windows file):

```
[
    { "keys": ["f5"], "command": "build" }
]
```

You can change f5 to another key if you wish

Save and reopen Sublime Text 2

Now go to Tools -> Build System

Click on the name of the build you created
`